# Concurrent Payment Control

Tags: python, mysql, django, concurrency, e-commerce

When I click on 'Place Order' I have begun the transaction and set the column **is_payment_processing** to True before taking the user to the merchant website and then there could be three possibilities:

1. User landed on success callback page
2. User landed on failure callback page
3. User landed neither on success nor on failure callback coz he closed the window.

In Third Scenario: The product will remain in the state where **is_payment_processing** is True. And, other users who attempt to check out the same product will not be able to do so. But in this case, I may lose some customers and cause some inconvenience.

*Thinking to have a cron job to run every minute which will track the last modification time of that column and if it is not been altered for more than 3 minutes then set that flag to False.*

What should be the best approach here? How in general scenario this is implemented? (Concurrency Control)

**Another Thought In Mind:**
[Visit this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577569/how-to-extend-the-locking-transaction-between-the-views)

Comment: Dont you have a mechanism to check with the merchant website to know if the transaction is still in progress?

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal: No, I can't unless the control doesn't go either on success or failure callback. coz I receive reference id from the vendor in those callback urls which I can use to query the status.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have a `stock` field in your `Product` model to keep the number of quantities available for that product.

When someone places an order, a separate `order` instance should be created with the number of quantities of the `Prodduct`  specified. The stock should only be reduced once the callback is received for that `order` or a webhook is received confirming the payment.

This would not prevent other customers from placing orders for the same product until the item has actually been sold.

Another approach could be to reduce the stock when the customer goes to the callback page and release the stock if the payment is not received within certain duration of time. Background task would be required for this.

**Note:** use `F` object from `django.models` while reducing the stock in order to  reduce the stock from the DB value and not the instance attribute.

Comment: First approach would cause an inconvenience if the customer bought the product and another user was able to buy the product before it the first customers transaction was completed. Here we would have to refund money to first customer, which might take upto a week

Answer (score 0):

Cron seems to be the best approach if you are able to(If you are on a shared host, many providers dont allow you any crons)

I might make the cron intelligent by checking if the transaction is still in progress. (Here I am assuming I have a mechanism to do so)

EDIT:
Please note, locking the inventory once the payment transaction is in progress, is pretty standard

Comment: I'm rendering the form which auto post the values to the vendor site during this view/transaction would have been completed and in the meantime, while the user is making a payment, the otheruser could initiate the order process before i start transaction on either of callback.