# How to extend the locking/transaction between the views?

Tags: mysql, django, transactions, django-views

I have the functionality where I want to extend the transaction between two views.

When a user clicks on 'Place Order' then the transaction begins and user is redirected to the merchant site to process the payment. In that case, where the control is not in the view where the transaction was written then How do I keep the locking alive unless the user returns on either of the defined callback URLs and then release it. (And, another story is when user don't even land on callback then is there a quick option to auto-release the lock if the transaction isn't completed in set time boundaries)

Comment: Why do you want to use transactions for this?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Please check this ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58576712/concurrent-payment-control  (I'm thinking if technically this is possible then i don't have to take the steps as i mentioned in the shared link)